# Clear cache in remote server using ssh

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, sudo, clear-cache

I had been trying to clear cache in a remote server and i got these commands.

First login as root user and execute

```
sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

But I had to automate this in a script, so i used this

ssh user@ipaddress "sudo su; sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches";

But I am not able to get the root user privileges by sudo su and I thought removing `sudo su` and instead use

```
ssh user@ipaddress "sudo sync;sudo echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches";
```

But this says it dose'nt have enough permissions.

What am I missing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this `sudo echo 3 > ....` only echo will be with "sudo" user permissions, redirection is with current user.

try something like this :

```
    ssh user@ipaddress "sudo sh -c \"sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `tee` as an alternate to redirection that works well with `sudo`:

```
ssh user@ipaddress 'echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches > /dev/null'
```

The redirection to `/dev/null` is optional, if you want to avoid "3" being echoed to your terminal as well.

Answer (score 0):

Also If you experience this message

```
>> sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

as I had, you can fix it by editing `/etc/sudoers` and comment `Defaults requiretty` -> `#Defaults requiretty`.